# ios7: custom animation for the delete view presentation on a table view cell?

Tags: uitableview, ios7

When using the UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete on ios7, the cell contents animates to the left.

I'd like to find a way to keep all the **information at the left side** of the cell visible with the accessory view. (eg. I preffer the ios6 option, where the delete button slides over the cell).

I tried:

- changing the frame in will/did transition to state gets jerky animation.
- using a custom editingAccessoryView (but this presents the same way as the default)

Is there an easy way of acheiving this?

Code on any tableView:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView ...... {
  return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

-(NSString *)tableView ... titleForDeleteConfirmation.... {
  return @"delete row";
}

- (void)tableView ... commitEditingStyle ... {
[self removeItem];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Gave this up as it introduces too much complexity, but using ios7 custom transitions should be the way to solve related problems.

Comment: [UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013059) may solve this kind of problem.